# EF 5 Code First keeps regenerating the cross table between subclasses using TPH

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-many, subclass, tph

In a Table-Per-Hierarchy schema, representing two subclasses in a M-M relationship with each other:

```
public class Project {

    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
    protected Project(){}
}

public class Subproject1 : Project {

    ...
    public virtual IList<Subproject2> LinkedSubprojects2 {get; set;}
}

public class Subproject2 : Project {

    ...
    public virtual IList<Subproject1> LinkedSubprojects1 {get; set;}
}
```

every once in a while I get the exception "The model backing the context has changed...", even if I have made no changes to my model.

I have looked at the proposed migration, and what it wants to do is drop the table `Subproject1Subproject2s` and replace it `with Subproject2Subproject1s`.

I have seen it do that once before, but then I was making model changes so I thought little of it. But it seems to have the potential of becoming a major problem, if it does so sporadically, by itself!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Subproject1>()
    .HasMany(p => p.LinkedSubprojects2)
    .WithMany(p => p.LinkedSubprojects1)
    .Map(r =>
        {
            r.MapLeftKey("Subproject1_Id");
            r.MapRightKey("Subproject2_Id");
            r.ToTable("Subproject1Subproject2s");
        });
```